# Xcode build fails

Tags: xcode, xcode11.3

Getting "Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's." after I add NotificationServiceExtension as a target to my project.

Solutions I have tried:

1. Ensured Code signing identity is same for Main app and Notification service Extension -> Didn't work build still fails.
2. Switched to legacy build system to see if the build succeeds -> Build fails.
3. Enabled Copy only when installing in Embed App Extensions -> Build succeeds with this but rich media push notifications won't work anymore.
4. Set $(ARCHS_STANDARD) as the the valid architecture for the Extension target. -> Build fails
5. Deleted derived data -> Still fails

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or code snippet of how you added $(ARCHS_STANDARD)? I would expect this to fix the problem, maybe you added that incorrectly?

Comment: This screenShot looks like you updated the architectures with $(ARCHS_STANDARD) not the valid Architecture. Could this be the case?